# Open in mode fullscreen with harfang's RenderInit()

Tags: python, directx, fullscreen, bgfx

I'm trying to open a screen in **fullscreen** mode.
My understanding is that `RenderInit` should be passed a specific flag:.

`RenderInit(width: int, height: int, reset_flags: ResetFlags)`

...but `ResetFlags` (an emum ?) doesn't seem to mention anything regarding the **fullscreen** mode :
https://dev.harfang3d.com/api/3.2.3/cpython/constants/#resetflags

(I'm working on Windows in DirectX, with the Python API btw)

Comment: Hi!
I'm genuinely interested in knowing what made you think the `ResetFlags` parameter would help you to switch to fullscreen (this could be an issue in the documentation, maybe it can be improved)

Comment: @Astrofra I found this information in the BGFX documentation : 
https://bkaradzic.github.io/bgfx/bgfx.html#_CPPv4N4bgfx5resetE8uint32_t8uint32_t8uint32_tN13TextureFormat4EnumE

Comment: AH! That's what I was afraid of... May I kindly point out that `BGFX_RESET_FULLSCREEN` says _Not supported yet_ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of `ResetFlags`. What you are looking for is a `WindowVisibility` flag :)
This code usually works for me:

```py
win = hg.NewWindow("My Fullscreen Window", 1920, 1080, 32, hg.WV_Fullscreen)
hg.RenderInit(win)
hg.RenderReset(res_x, res_y, hg.RF_MSAA4X | hg.RF_MaxAnisotropy)
```

Besides, `WV_Undecorated` works well if you don't want to change the user's screen resolution, or `WV_FullscreenMonitor1` (.., 2, 3) if you need to adress a specific screen in a multiple monitors configuration.